# I have a Swift Package and I want to know how to get the current version of this package

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

Similar to how you get your apps version `kCFBundleVersionKey` how does one get the version of the package you are working in?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @Kudit not really best approach is still the suggested answer by Luca D'Alberti below

Answer (score 10):

I don't think it's possible at the moment to get the value easily.
You can either read the `Package.resolved` file or you can set up a public constant where you would define the version of your library.

```swift
public let version = "0.0.1"

import MyLibrary

print(MyLibrary.version)
```

There isn't a standard way how to do this, every package could have a different constant (or not have it at all)

Comment: that is helpful, how would i read the `Package.resolved` file from swift ?

Comment: You would have to read the file (using `FileManager` or directly with `Data`) and then convert it to something you can read, for example using `Decodable`.
Otherwise you could check whether the Swift Package Manager library provides an API to inspect the libraries.

Answer (score 5):

You can check package version rules in project package dependencies tab. Check screenshot below. Propably it would be sufficient for most use cases.
[image]

Comment: I think the author wants to access the versions dynamically, so this doesn't help during runtime

Comment: How do you open this window?

Comment: @Zorayr in the left pane click on Project name and then select project -> build dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Edit: The context has changed, the question was to get the version of `MyPackage` I'm working on via code. There isn't any documented or recommended method as of now. Though this can be achieved by a hack through reading the `Package.resolved` file as mentioned by Malcolm.

I'm not deleting this answer for any future users who are looking for answer on how to get the exact latest version of a Package.

You can give the same major version number and give `Update to latest package version` option on Xcode. eg: If current version is 2.4.5 you just need to provide 2.0.0 and update. There is also an option to provide the exact version of swift package you need.

[image: This is how]

Comment: this is to install the package, im looking for the version from within the source class of the package

Comment: "Source class of the package", what exactly does that mean?

Comment: I am writing the package so the `entry` point into the package where you traditionally call `Package.init()`

Comment: Inside a package you get a folder called `Sources`

Comment: So you are asking how to know which Source of the package you have in your local system?

Comment: When you release your package you give it a tag in GitHub. that tag is used by others to install your package. I want to know that tag from within my code

Comment: Ok, now I get it, I don't think if it's possible currently.